# Is the support of a compactly supported function on $\Omega$ a proper subset of $\Omega$?

Tags: analysis, compactness

Let $d\in\mathbb N$ and $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be open. Is there some continuous $\phi:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ with compact support $\operatorname{supp}$ and $\operatorname{supp}\phi=\overline{\Omega}$?

Comment: How are you defining $C^0(\Omega)$?

Comment: @AhmedHussein: Wasn't sure if the OP meant for $\phi$ to be defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^d$ or just near $\Omega$.

Comment: Sure: It's easy to do it for $\mathbb{R}$, and extend it to higher $\mathbb{R}^d$ by, for example, defining $\phi$ radially.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Continuous functions from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: What about the "$0$" superscript?

Comment: @UmbertoP. "$0$ times continuously differentiable". It's just cause I usually denote these spaces by $C^k(\Omega)$.

Comment: Are you asking whether we can always find such a $\Omega$? Just take $\Omega$ to be bounded and $\phi$ constant and non-zero on $\Omega$.

Comment: The overbar in your definition of ${\rm supp}\>\phi$ and in $\bar\Omega$ mean different things: In the first case it is the closure in $\Omega$, and in the second the closure in ${\mathbb R}^d$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter So, $\operatorname{supp}\phi$ is impossible to be $\overline\Omega$, by definition?

Comment: @0xbadf00d I'm not sure how to interpret your answer.

Comment: @AlexProvost Given an open $\Omega$. Is it possible that there is some continuous $\phi:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ with compact support $\operatorname{supp}\phi=\overline{\Omega}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Omega$ be the open unit ball and let $\phi(x) = 1$.  Then by your definition of support, $\mathrm{supp\, }\phi = \overline \Omega$.

Comment: The support should be defined as in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)#Closed_support).

Comment: The compactness property is relative to $\Omega$ (not $\mathbb R^d$). So, in your example, $\phi$ has not compact support.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Compactness is a topological property and is independent of the ambient space...

Comment: Please take a look at the [answer of Christian Blatter](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1859627/47771). By definition, $\operatorname{supp}\phi$ is a strict subset of $\Omega$.

Answer (score 1):

Given a topological space $\Omega$, e.g., a subset of ${\mathbb R}^d$ given the relative topology, and a  function $\phi:\>\Omega\to{\mathbb R}$ the *support* of $\phi$ is by definition the closure (in $\Omega$) of the set of $x\in\Omega$ where $\phi(x)\ne 0$:
$${\rm supp}\>\phi=\overline{\{x\in\Omega\>|\>\phi(x)\ne0\}}\ \subset\Omega\ ,$$
and is a subset of the given space $\Omega$. Note that $\Omega=\bar\Omega$ in this context.

Example: If $\Omega\subset{\mathbb R}^2$ is the open unit disc, and $\phi(x)=1-|x|$, then ${\rm supp}\>\phi=\Omega$, since $\phi$ is nonvanishing on $\Omega$. If $\Omega\subset{\mathbb R}^2$ is the closed unit disc, and $\phi(x)=1-|x|$, then ${\rm supp}\>\phi=\Omega$ as well, since no point on the unit circle has a neighborhood on which $\phi$ vanishes identically.

All of this has nothing to do with the fact that $\Omega$ might be a subspace of some larger space $X$. If the latter is the case then $\Omega$ has a closed hull in $X$. But even if this hull is a compact set larger than $\Omega$ this would not make the support $S$ of $\phi$, as defined in $(1)$, compact if $S$ didn't have this property right from the outset.

Comment: There is no $(1)$.

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence. If $\Omega$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^d$, it has a closed hull in $\mathbb R^d$, but as you've said, the definition of $\operatorname{supp}\phi$ is relative to $\Omega$ equipped with the subspace topology.

Comment: @0xbadf00d The point is that when we say a function has compact support in $\Omega$, we mean that its support (defined relative to $\Omega$) is compact (again relative to $\Omega$). If its support is actually all of $\Omega$ (which is fine, since $\Omega$ is closed in itself) then it is not compact, because $\Omega$ is not a compact subset of itself (if it is open). This is despite the fact that if we were to extend $\phi$ to $\mathbb{R}^d$ somehow, then it could happen that its support was $\overline{\Omega}$ which is compact as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ (assuming $\Omega$ was bounded).

Comment: @0xbadf00d So for example, a function in $C_0(\Omega)$ (so it vanishes at the boundary) can be extended to a function in $C_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$ (by defining it to be zero outside $\Omega$). But it is nevertheless not in $C_c(\Omega)$.

Comment: @Ian What you mean is that by this extension of $\phi$ to $\mathbb R^d$, the symbol sequence $\operatorname{supp}\phi$ has to be understood in a different way, cause now everything is relative to $\mathbb R^d$ (and not $\Omega$ anymore). Did I got you right?

Answer (score 0):

> For *any* open $\Omega$, does there exist a continuous $\phi:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ with compact support equal to $\overline{\Omega}$?

No. Consider $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^d$. Then the support of any compactly supported function will never equal $\overline{\mathbb{R}^d} = \mathbb{R}^d$, which is not compact.

---

More generally, we have the inclusions $\operatorname{supp}\phi \subset \Omega \subset \overline{\Omega}$. The latter inclusion is strict if and only if $\Omega$ isn't closed. Therefore the *only* way to possibly have $\operatorname{supp} \phi = \overline{\Omega}$ is for $\Omega$ to be both open and closed, i.e., $\Omega = \emptyset$ or $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^d$.

If $\Omega = \emptyset$, the empty function trivially satisfies your request.

If $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^d$, there is no function that satisfies your request, as I've shown above.

Comment: I've rephrased the question and hopefully it's now clear what I mean.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Thank you. Does my answer satisfy you?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Please reread my question. Given an *unknown* open $\Omega$, can we guarantee that there is no such $\phi$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Better now?

Comment: Please take a look at the [answer of Christian Blatter](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1859627/47771). By definition, $\operatorname{supp}\phi$ is a strict subset of $\Omega$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Well I was working off your definition of support...

Comment: I'm sorry, if I confused you with my definition. I thought there would be one definition of support everyone knows.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Anyway, my answer still stands.

Comment: But it's not an answer to my question. As I said, you're not allowed to choose a specific $\Omega$. $\Omega$ is fixed in the question. Maybe the following question will clarify what I'm after: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1859662/partial-integration-for-smooth-functions-with-compact-support

Comment: @0xbadf00d But it is an answer to your question. I've shown that the answer is: **No**, in general, there won't be a $\phi \in C^0(\Omega)$ with compact support equal to $\overline{\Omega}$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I've covered all possible cases in my edit.